# Unable to install fedy on Fedora 22

Tags: installation, fedora

I am following this guide:- [Here](http://www.unixmen.com/tweak-your-fedora-22-desktop-using-fedy-and-postinstallerf/)

In short it tells to do following:-

Download the latest version using the command:

```
wget http://satya164.github.io/fedy/fedy-installer
```

Set executable permission and install as shown below:

```
chmod +x fedy-installer

sudo ./fedy-installer
```

To install Fedy on Fedora 22.

But I am getting the following error.

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# sudo ./fedy-installer
Adding repositories...
Installing fedy...
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'ozonos' from 'http://goodies.ozon-os.com/repo/22/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried, disabling.
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:27:26 ago on Fri Jul 24 14:11:58 2015.
No package fedy available.
Error: no package matched: fedy
```

I tried opening **goodies.ozon-os.com/repo/22/** but it is not opening on my firefox browser....is there another way to install fedy on fedora 22?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To install fedy, try the steps provided here: http://folkswithhats.org/

The host site for Ozon OS repository (http://goodies.ozon-os.com/) seems to be down, probably permanently, not sure if it has been moved or abandoned. It's no longer needed for upgrading fedy.

You can either remove the repo from your list...

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/ozonos.repo
```

...or, if still unsure, just disable it

```
dnf config-manager --set-disabled ozonos
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bash -c 'su -c "curl http://folkswithhats.org/fedy-installer -o fedy-installer && chmod +x fedy-installer && ./fedy-installer"'
```